# How to reformat a c structure in ida pro

Tags: arm, disassembly, ida, radare2

I'm trying to disassemble a arm64 based binary I want to know how can I reformat structure as it was before I mean not strings but the values at least placed that they were before in code?
Take example

```
static struct mystruct cmn = {
      { 0xFF, 0x03, {0x98, 0x81, 0x03} },
      { 0x01, 0x01, {0x00} },
      { 0x02, 0x01, {0x00} },
      { 0x03, 0x01, {0x53} },
};
```

But in binary it's actually hard to remember and I sometimes make mistakes while reversing. So, it possible to get a exactly same arranged chars in ida pro 7.2 or radare 2?

https://del.dog/raw/fomukovata

Comment: The data you are asking about is not stored as part of the compiled code.  You would have to look for instances in the binary where the structure is accessed and use that to derive the format of the data in memory (the original structure)

Answer (score 0):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- **radare2:** radare2 4.2.0-git 23519 @ linux-x86-64 git.4.1.1-84-g0c46c3e1e commit: 0c46c3e1e30bb272a5a05fc367d874af32b41fe4 build: 2020-01-08__09:49:0
- **system:** Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

***SOLUTION***

- As @David Hoelzer mentioned you must first derive the format of the data in memory.
- If you know the structure of the data we can use two commands in radare2 to structure that area of memory.

  - Command 1: pf.name [0|cnt]fmt   #      Define a new named format
  - Command 2: Cf[?][-] [sz] [0|cnt][fmt] [a0 a1...] [@addr] # format memory (see pf?)

***EXAMPLE***

Following the structure close to what you provided.

```sh
user@host:~$ r2 /bin/ls
[0x1000011e8]> pf.mystruct [5]c[3]c[3]c[3]c
[0x1000011e8]> Cf 14 ? (mystruct)example
[0x1000011e8]> pd 1
            ;-- rip:
            0x1000011e8 format ? (mystruct)example {
 example :
                struct<mystruct>
0x1000011e8 = [ 'U', 'H', '.', '.', 'A' ]
0x1000011ed = [ 'W', 'A', 'V' ]
0x1000011f0 = [ 'A', 'U', 'A' ]
0x1000011f3 = [ 'T', 'S', 'H' ]
} 14
[0x1000011e8]> q
user@host:~$
```

Comment: Also consider checking out https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ for reverse engineering questions!